# Is it better to give default values to your instance variables in onCreate, onResume or just when declaring them?

Tags: java, android

Is it better to give default values to your instance variables in onCreate, onResume or just when declaring them? In code:

When declaring them:

```
public Class Foo extends Activity{

    private String variable1 = "my super var";
    private int variable2 = 42;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

OR during onCreate

```
public class Foo extends Activity{

    private String variable1;
    private int variable2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        variable1 = "my super var";
        variable2 = 42;
    }
}
```

OR during on resume:

```
public class Foo extends Activity{

    private String variable1;
    private int variable2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        variable1 = "my super var";
        variable2 = 42;
    }   
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: That depends of your app lifecycle..., but maybe onResume is the choice, in my case, i use onCreate to set listeners and every visual stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above answers are good, and it does depend on coding style BUT, as a rule, try to avoid assigning default values other than when the variables are declared.  This will help with maintainability.  When you come back to your code in 6 months to fix a weird bug, having defaults scattered throughout the code will add to your troubles.

Only use onCreate, onResume etc if there is a purpose in doing so and then, add a meaningful comment e.g.

```
// re-initialise foobarValue when the app regains focus
// to ensure that the wobbly gong generator starts from the beginning
foobarValue = 1;
```

Cheers

Comment: Would also add to this the liberal use of static final values for use for one's initialized defaults as a way of aggregating all of your defaults into one place.

Answer (score 2):

That all depends on your sense of coding style, and of course the instance variables being assigned.  Often, a fair number of my instance variables are views and thus depend on having a valid context - so these I of course put in `onCreate()`.  If I need a variable to be reset every time I leave an activity and return, then it **has** to be in `onResume()`.  As for inline, I tend to do this when I know that the variable will not change and shouldn't change, and I make them `final`.  The balance between inline constructed variables and `onCreate()` depends.  Some people might like to have all of their assignments in one place, so `onCreate()` makes sense as a way to capture all assignments in a single location, if you don't care than there's no real performance difference between them, so put the assignment where you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a whole lot of difference from doing it as default values or in `onCreate` if the values are simple. What `onCreate` is good for is if you need activity-related things like a `Context` or something from the `Intent`, etc. Then you have to do it in `onCreate`.

However, doing this initialization in `onCreate` vs. `onResume` makes a huge difference. If you put code in `onResume` it runs every time you regain focus in the activity (for an exact definition you'll want to read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)). This means that if you press home and then go back to your app, this code will run again. So it really depends on what behavior you want.